# Ubuntu Command Line Jupyter Notebook Clear Screen

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I have seen this done, but can't for the life of me find it.

I have Jupyter Notebook installed on Ubuntu 16.04. in order to run it I type

jupyter notebook

Which gives me the familiar five lines to show it is running.

How do I get the cursor prompt back? Otherwise I either have to stop the notebook or open another SSH window.

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try using an ampersand after the jupyter notebook command:

```
jupyter notebook &
```

The ampersand makes the process run in the background and you get the cursor back.